# Authorising native app user with Google ID token and Laravel Socialite gives 401

Tags: php, laravel, react-native, oauth-2.0, laravel-socialite

I have an issue with Socialite authentication via Google. I have two separate apps: Laravel and React Native. For react native app I use @react-native-community/google-signin and after getting a token on the client I'm sending it to the Laravel app, where I pass this token into Socialite function: Socialite::driver('google')->userFromToken($token); . I get this error:

```
Client error: GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false resulted in a 401 Unauthorized response:
{
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid Credentials"
}
```

I've rechecked credentials 4 times and I'm sure they are right. I use the same client id as in react native app. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I am using ID token to authorise instead of auth token.

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to implement one-tap sign in (EDIT: missed the google-signin package in your post sorry). When socialite calls to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2` it is expecting an access token and not an ID token.

Answer (score 2):

From my research on a similar issue - It looks like Google one tap doesn't work in the same way as oAuth does.
So, you'd have to fetch a user from the `$token` manually, using the `google/apiclient` package.

There's an example in Google docs (it's in the `android`-section, but these particular snippets refer to back-end part, so it should still do the trick)

`composer require google/apiclient`

```php
// Get $id_token via HTTPS POST.

$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  //$domain = $payload['hd'];
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
}
```

You can find more info on this [Google Docs Page](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/idtoken-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library)